# Show that $1 + \sqrt{2}$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm a beginner to number theory, and in a text book, right after proving the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, the following problem is stated:

Let $H_m$ be the subset of real numbers, which can be written in the form of $x + y\sqrt{m}$, where $x$ and $y$ are integers and $m$ isn't a square number.
Show that besides $\pm1$, $1 + \sqrt{2}$ and $3 + 2\sqrt{2}$ are also units in $H_2$. The book recommends defining divisibility, units and undecomposablity in the $H_m$ set first.

How should I begin solving the problem? Any kind of help is welcome.

(I'm not that familiar with the technicalities in English, I'm sorry.)

Comment: Do you know what a unit is?  If so, just try to show that $1+\sqrt 2$ has an inverse in that set.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: I tried to show it by saying that $x + y\sqrt{2} = (1 + \sqrt{2})(n + m\sqrt{2})$, where $n$ and $m$ are integers, but that led to nowhere reasonable. And an integer is a unit if it is a divisor of every integer. And in this context I guess a unit like $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a divisor of every number in the form of $x+y\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Say $1=(1+\sqrt2)(n+m\sqrt2)$

Comment: You should look up what a [unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)) is. Or do you mean some other unit?

Comment: Ah, I see. So it is eneugh to show that there exists $n$ and $m$ integers that satisfy $1 = (1 + \sqrt{2})(n + m\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: Yes; if $ab=1$, then $a$ divides any element $c$, because $a(bc)=c$

Comment: Thanks for adding a comment to show your efforts.  The protocol here is to include those efforts in the post itself (editing the post if necessary).  Would you mind doing that so that your question (standing alone) meets the site's guidelines?

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, everyone who commented. <3
I also edited the question, such that it meets the guidlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(1+\sqrt 2)(-1+\sqrt2) =-1+\sqrt2-\sqrt2 +2=-1+2=1.$$

$\therefore 1+\sqrt2 $ is a unit in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2].$

The way I got it was: $$(1+\sqrt2) (1-\sqrt2) =-1.$$

So just multiply $$1-\sqrt2 $$ by $$-1.$$

Of course,  $$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2,$$ and the other one's inverse is simply the "conjugate", $3-2\sqrt2. $

---

It's possible to define a "norm" on $\Bbb Z[\sqrt m] $ by $N(a+b\sqrt m) =a^2-mb^2$ and verify that it's *multiplicative*. As a result,  $a+b\sqrt m$ is a unit exactly when $N(a+b\sqrt m) =\pm1.$

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by the conjugate to rationalize the denominator:  $\dfrac1{1+\sqrt2}=\dfrac1{1+\sqrt2}\dfrac{1-\sqrt2}{1-\sqrt2}=\dfrac{1-\sqrt2}{-1}=\sqrt2-1$

Answer (score 1):

So the solution turned out to be:
$$1 = (1 + \sqrt{2})(n + m\sqrt{2})$$
We have to show that $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$. If they are, then $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a unit, otherwise it isn't.
$$1 = n + m\sqrt{2} + n\sqrt{2} + 2m$$
$$1 = (n + 2m) + (m + n)\sqrt{2}$$
$1$ can be written in the form as $1 + 0\sqrt{2}$, so therefore by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic:
$$n + 2m = 1 \quad\wedge\quad m + n = 0$$
By solving this equation system, we get that $m=1$ and $n = -1$, which are integers, therefore we can conclude that $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a unit in $H_2$. The other unit, $3 + 2\sqrt{2}$ can be shown similarly.

Comment: It turns out that if $x^2-my^2=1$ than $x+y\sqrt m$ is a unit in $H_m$. Indeed, $(x+y\sqrt m)\cdot(x-y\sqrt m)= x^2-my^2=1$. See [Pell’s equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

Comment: What does the fundamental theorem of arithmetic have to do with anything? You probably mean the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @Eric the development in a text can be tight,  but not necessarily that tight.   Besides,  there's a connection with factorization and prime ideals in an integral domain (a generalization of the integers).

Answer (score 1):

Units in a ring $R$ form a group $U$ called the group of units. It is easy to see this. In particular, if $x\in U$ then $x^n\in U$ for any $n\in\Bbb Z.$

We can easily see that $x=\sqrt2 +1$ is a unit in the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]$:
$$1=2-1=(\sqrt2+1)(\sqrt2-1).$$ So, $x^2=3+2\sqrt2$ is a unit as well.  As in some sense said, we can use "Norm" of the ring to show that a number is a unit.

There is a [very deep theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_unit_theorem) about the group structure of the group of units in the ring of algebraic integers of a number field.